# Wipe option is missing

Tags: factory-reset, lenovo, hard-reset

I lost password for my phone and now I cannot unlock. I think only option what I have is completely wipe device (data lost is not matter). I googled many manuals and videos and it looked very easy. Boot into recovery menu and click to wipe button but in my case **there is no wipe option**. I's really weird because the resources what I found was for the exactly same device (region differences?).

How to wipe this device? Do I need to have special cable? Which one?

Model: Lenovo K5 PRO (L38041)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does your device has a Google account signed in and can it be connected to internet? If yes, you should be able to wipe data using Google's Find my device. https://support.google.com/android/answer/6160491?hl=en

Comment: even after factory reset google play password is required because of FRP (factory reset protection)

Comment: @Firelord Awesome man! I tried the same post at XDA forums a few weeks ago and without response. Now, your idea saved my nephew phone :) Fortunately brother in law enabled location services when installed this phone so wipe using this service was successful.

Comment: Cool. Have you been able to successfully boot into home screen after wipe?

Comment: Yes. I'm not an android user but it looked like setup screen.